# Get all dates in a week

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

When I select a date from dual. I have to display all the dates in particular week with days.

First I get week number using

```
select to_char(sysdate,'iw') FROM dual
```

By using week number I want to get all the dates of that particular week. I used this.

```
SELECT (TRUNC ( TO_DATE (SUBSTR ('201704', 1, 4) 
         || '0131', 'YYYY'|| 'MMDD'), 'IYYY') +
              ( 7 * ( TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR ('201704', 5)) - 1)) ) AS iw
FROM   DUAL
```

---

my input is sysdate.

I Have to get o/p as below.

```
23-Jan-2017
24-Jan-2017
25-Jan-2017
26-Jan-2017
27-Jan-2017
28-Jan-2017
29-Jan-2017
```

Comment: Where's your code?  See: [ask]

Comment: C'mon - when you post a homework question you have to include the code you've written, tell us what results you expected, what you got, and what's wrong with what you got. Otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: mr C'mon please check nw and thank u for ur feedback

Comment: my input is sysdate   required output is dates of this week

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select trunc(sysdate,'IW') + level - 1
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

If you want to manually provide the date instead of sysdate, you can e.g. do this:

```
select trunc(to_date('10-Feb-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy'),'IW') + level - 1
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

If you want to apply this on more than one date, use cross join:

```
with t(dt) as (
  select to_date('23-Jan-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual union all
  select to_date('01-Mar-2017','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
)
-- test data ends here

select dt, trunc(dt,'IW') + n dt2
from t cross join (
      select level - 1 n
      from dual
      connect by level <= 7
);
```

Comment: not from table i entered manually                                                          select trunc('04-Apr-2017','W') + level
from dual
connect by level <= 7;

Comment: By *it's not working* - do you mean you get an error? please post here the date? did you use to_date function?

Comment: but it gets saturday to friday nly i need monday to sunday      check this                                                                             select trunc(to_date('28-Sep-2017'),'W') + level
from dual
connect by level <= 7;

Comment: You modified the query incorrectly. Use `SELECT TRUNC(to_date('28-Sep-2017'),'IW') + level - 1
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 7;` Notice **IW** and **level - 1**. IW is for ISO week - which is monday to sunday